# Using tkinter filedialog.askdirectory to choose paths and preform a script using those paths

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, macos-catalina, filedialog, listdir

I have a project where I'm creating a simple GUI where the user chooses a source and destination directory using `filedialog.askdirectory()` that does two things.

1. Displays the chosen path into an entry box for 'visible' verification.
2. Initializes two variables with each path as a string, respectively. Then these two variables are used in a script that moves any files created or modified in the source directory, within the last 24 hours, to the destination directory.

I am able to create the program and GUI up to choosing the two paths and them being displayed in the Entry boxes. However, I am running into an issue getting the output of the two paths from `filedialog.askdirectory()` into the script that finds and moves the files.

**This is what I have so far:**

**"Main file"**

```py
# Import required python modules
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import os
import shutil
from datetime import time

# Import custom module identifiers
import testfunc
import testgui


class ParentWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.master = master
        self.master.maxsize(700, 500)
        self.master.minsize(700, 500)
        self.master.title("Directory Auto-Sync®")
        self.master.config(bg="#333")
        self.master.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda: testfunc.quit_message(self))

        testfunc.center_window(self, 700, 500)
        testgui.load_gui(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App = ParentWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**"GUI File"**

```py
# Import required python modules
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

# Import custom module identifiers
import testfunc
import testmain


def load_gui(self):
    self.src_lbl = tk.Label(
        self.master,
        font=("Helvetica", 16),
        fg="#fff",
        bg="#333",
        text="Choose Source Directory",
    )
    self.src_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(160, 0), pady=(50, 0), sticky=NSEW)
    self.src_lbl.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.src_ent = tk.Entry(self.master, width=40)
    self.src_ent.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(160, 0), pady=(5, 0), sticky=NSEW)
    self.src_ent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.src_btn = tk.Button(
        self.master,
        highlightbackground="#333",
        text="Browse",
        command=lambda: testfunc.src_dir(self),
    )
    self.src_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(160, 0), pady=(10, 0), sticky=NSEW)
    self.src_btn.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.dest_lbl = tk.Label(
        self.master,
        font=("Helvetica", 16),
        fg="#fff",
        bg="#333",
        text="Choose Destination Directory",
    )
    self.dest_lbl.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(160, 0), pady=(50, 0), sticky=NSEW)
    self.dest_lbl.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.dest_ent = tk.Entry(self.master, width=40)
    self.dest_ent.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=(160, 0), pady=(5, 0), sticky=NSEW)
    self.dest_ent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.dest_btn = tk.Button(
        self.master,
        highlightbackground="#333",
        text="Browse",
        command=lambda: testfunc.dest_dir(self),
    )
    self.dest_btn.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=(160, 0), pady=(10, 0), sticky=NSEW)
    self.dest_btn.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

**"Function File"**

```py
# Import required python modules
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
import sqlite3

# Import custom module identifiers
import testgui
import testmain


def center_window(self, w, h):
    wscreen = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
    hscreen = self.master.winfo_screenheight()
    x = int((wscreen / 2) - (700 / 2))
    y = int((hscreen / 2) - (500 / 2))
    cscreen = self.master.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(w, h, x, y))
    return cscreen


def quit_message(self):
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Directory Auto-Sync®", "Did you really want to quit Directory Auto-Sync®?"):
        self.master.destroy()
        sys.exit()._exit(0)


def src_dir(self):
    dirpath = filedialog.askdirectory()
    x = dirpath + "/"
    self.src_ent.insert(END, x)
    
    return


def dest_dir(self):
    dir_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    x = dir_path + "/"
    self.dest_ent.insert(END, x)
    return


# def relay_source():
#     src = var_s.get()
#     return src
#
#
# def relay_dest():
#     dest = var_d.get()
#     return dest


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

**How it looks:**
[image: My tkinter directory syncing app]

As you can see from the **function file** I am not sure how to proceed. I do have the following script that I know works if you enter in the directories manually (into the script itself), but not using the `filedialog.askdirectory()` method described above.

**Script to move files:**

```py
def current_milli_time():
    x = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    return x


def move_files():
    # s = var_s.get()
    # source = os.listdir(s))
    # x = '/'
    # files = os.path.join(source, x)
    # print(files)
    # for i in files:
    #     paths = os.path.join(source, i)
    #     file_birth = os.stat(paths).st_birthtime
    #     file_modify = os.stat(paths).st_mtime
    #     if (current_milli_time() / 1000) - file_birth < 86400 or (
    #             current_milli_time() / 1000
    #     ) - file_modify < 86400:
    #          d = var_d + "/"
    #         shutil.copy2(paths, d)
    #     else:
    #         print("\n{} already in directory".format(paths))
    # return
```

So as you can see I am linking the files with import modules since I'm not sure how I would do this all in one file, at least not yet. Also, I am new here and apologize for this being so long winded. I just wanted to give as much detail as possible. Thank you very much and I really look forward to what you guys think!